# How to configure analyzers in ElasticRay?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer, liferay-6.2

I was able to configure it through sense and through pure java... but haven't found any resources to do it using elasticray ... I am using Liferay 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change the `template.json` file located in [`webs/elasticray-web/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/rknowsys/portal/search/elastic`](https://github.com/R-Knowsys/elasticray/tree/master/webs/elasticray-web/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/rknowsys/portal/search/elastic) to suit your changes.

Then you can rebuild the WAR and redeploy it inside Liferay. That will do the job.